# Formatação de valores decimais .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

Considerando o código abaixo, como consigo alterar o retorno de `.7777` para `0.7777`?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Teste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal x = 0.7777M;
            var y = x.ToString("#.#######", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque? está fazendo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria isso ?

```
decimal x = 0.7777M;
var y = x.ToString("0.0000", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
Console.WriteLine(y);
```